# Verifying the Numbers in a Sector of a Sudoku

Tags: java, generator, sudoku, verify

I am trying to verify whether there are two or more identical numbers in a sector of a Sudoku game. Can anybody help me? Here is what I have so far. My code is in java.

```
public static boolean isInSector(int[][] grid, int line, int column, int value) {
        boolean find = false;
        int size = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < grid.length / size && !find; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < grid[0].length / size && !find; j++) {
                if (grille[(line / size) + i][(column / size) + j] == value) {
                    trouve = true;
                }
            }
        }
        return find;
    }
```

Thank you

Comment: First of all `grid.length / 0`  will result to `DivideByZeroException`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you need to verify if the `value` in range `[1..9]` that should be put into cell `[line, column]` is not used neither in the `line`, nor in the `column`.  Also, usually the sudoku field is square, so there's no need to use nested loop and possible solution is as simple as:

```java
public static boolean isInSector(int[][] grid, int line, int column, int value) {
    for (int i = 0, n = grid.length; i < n; i++) {
        if (grid[line][i] == value || grid[i][column] == value) {
            return true;  // a value already exists in the field
        }
    }
    // the value is not found in the given line and column
    return false;
}
```